# React.js Drag functions in Chrome suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I was just working now on my react drag-and-drop function and suddenly, my code to handle Drag or Drop events just stopped working, but only in Chrome. In all my other browsers.. edge, firefox etc. it still works normally with my code. Why is that?
Could it be an issue with Chrome only or maybe an extension?

```
const handleDragOver = e => {
    console.log('DRAGOVER!')
    // if (!editMode) return
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
    setIsDraggedOver(true)
    setDragoverText('Release to upload file')
}

<div 
onDragOver={e => handleDragOver(e)} 
onDragLeave={e => handleDragLeave(e)} 
onDrop={e => handleDrop(e)} 
className={`border-2 h-auto w-auto rounded-md flex flex-col items- center justify-center  box-border  ${ isDraggedOver ? 'border-solid' : 'border-dashed' }`}>
```

EDIT: Since today (3.10) it all works normally again.. weird?!